# can not login using express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, bcryptjs

hello everyone getting this problem can not login getting server error which is in catch part checked credential and evryhting is okay getting the data in req.body but getting nothing when console log userr can anyone plz tell me what can be the problem with this

const login = async (req, res) =>{
try {

```
    const {email, password} = req.body;
   console.log(req.body);
    const userExists = await findOne({email});
    console.log(userExists);
    if (!userExist) {
        return res.status(400).json({message: "invalid credentials"});
    }

    const userr = await bcrypt.compare(password, userExists.password);

    if (userr) {
        
        res.status(200).json({ 
        msg:"login succesfull",
        token: await userExists.generateToken(),
        userId: userExists._id.toString(),});
    }
  
    else{
        res.status(401).json({msg:"invalid email or password"});
    }

} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({msg:"server error "});
}
```

}

i have created registration also which is working fine the data is being stored in database,
but the login functionality is not working .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the credentials are correct check once by correcting the typo error and try "userExist" to "userExists" in if block

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).